# CSS - Trying to remove white space on website

Tags: html, css, layout

This website is built with a back-end web to print service called Zoo Printing. The client I work for does not like the original design so I've being hired to re-design it with the development team that handles the back-end. I replaced their old navigation menu with the current CSS mega navigation that's on the site. Their developers decided to keep their code on the website for back up just in case they need to roll-back to the old navigation. The issue is even though their code is commented out, it creates a huge white space between my CSS slideshow and footer.  Their developers are blaming my code and will not tell me where the problem is coming from. Can one of you inspect my code and tell me what would be causing this? I've tried simply removing the white space with CSS by absolute positioning it off the page, but when i do this the footer changes on every page except the home and it also removes my CSS slide show. I can not figure out how to remove this white space without messing with my layout.

The website is [Advanced Litho](http://www.advancedlitho.com)

```
body > div:nth-child(4)
```

This is the div that's creating the issues with the layout. So far I've tried to absolute position it off the page with no luck.

Comment: That guy's face on the slider scares me...

Comment: Me too. lol Not my choice for the images on the slide show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are unordered lists inside `<div class="nav_child"></div>`

If you can remove them, it is best to do so, otherwise you can hide them with css and get rid of the white space:

```
.nav_child ul {
   display: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It was hard for me to notice that because it's on their server, and they only let me upload code to it. I have no idea why they did that, but thank you so much for telling me how to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a div at the bottom that is making the space huge, it is right above the commented out content and right below the div with id=content. All of these boxes have a visibility of hidden which does not delete them from your page, it simply makes them invisible. All you need to do is find that div, and insert an inline style.

```
<div style="display: none;">(old nav)</div>
```

Essentially, they just hid what they were supposed to remove.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was hard for me to notice that because it's on their server, and they only let me upload code to it. I have no idea why they did that, but thank you so much for telling me how to remove it.